# Need help, I need to create code, button and repeating texts appear

Tags: javascript, cookies

now I remaking 1 website and I need to make one thing, there will be button, when user click on button he got text with some text I would create, for example:

User click on button and he got text "Hello 123"

He leave page, come back after some time, click on button and he got another text, like "Hello 321"

He refresh page, or leave and come back, click on button and got another text like "Hello 231"

And so on, until my all texts I created will end and then they should repeat again from first.

Any ideas how to make this working? I think I should use cookies, to remember user clicks on button, but I don't have any experience with cookies, maybe anyone could help?

I done something like this, but I need that every user, after leaving page, or refreshing page would get text in rotation. Sorry for my english, it's very hard for me to translate my language to english in this topic.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="textafterclicked()">Click on me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function textafterclicked() {
    var r_text = new Array (); 
r_text[0] = "Hello 123"; 
r_text[1] = "Hello 321"; 
r_text[2] = "Hello 312"; 
r_text[3] = "Goodbye 123"; 
r_text[4] = "Goodbye 321"; 

var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random()); 

document.write("<center><FONT SIZE=72><FONT COLOR='BLACK'>" + 
r_text[i]  + "</FONT></center>"); 



document.body.style.background=bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FP00EY31A07Z

Comment: Should the text only rotate for a user, or should it rotate globally ?

Comment: Only for a user. Text should be changed after he clicks on button, and if he leaves, come back and again clicks on button, he should get text from last time he clicked. So for each user it's different. If you know what I mean, if not I will try to explain different. Thanks

Comment: I updated a bit your code and gave a js-only solution.

Comment: hey, does my answer help you solving your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a JS solution only and want to use cookies you need smaller helper function to get and set cookies n the browser. I added a `getCookie(name)` and `setCookie(name, value, days)` function to your code.

Here are the steps:

1. Get cookie named `myIndex`
2. If cookie not set, init with 0
3. Do view stuff
4. If `myIndex` is in range of your array `r_text` -> increment
5. If `myIndex` is out of range -> remove cookie

Here is your code. Please make sure you open it on localhost or on a domain. Otherwise you cannot access the cookies.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="textafterclicked()">Click on me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function getCookie(name) {
    var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return v ? v[2] : null;
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var d = new Date;
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000*days);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    return value;
}

var i = getCookie('myIndex'); 
console.info(i);

if (!i){
 i = setCookie('myIndex', 0, 365);
}

var r_text = new Array (); 
 r_text[0] = "Hello 0"; 
 r_text[1] = "Hello 1"; 
 r_text[2] = "Hello 2"; 
 r_text[3] = "Hello 3"; 
 r_text[4] = "Hello 4"; 


function textafterclicked() {

 i = parseInt(i);
 
 document.write("<center><FONT SIZE=72><FONT COLOR='BLACK'>" +  r_text[i]  + "</FONT></center>"); 

 if(i >= r_text.length - 1){
  setCookie('myIndex', '', -1); // delete 
 }else{
  setCookie('myIndex', '', -1); // delete first
  i = setCookie('myIndex', i+1, 365); // set it with incremented value
 }

// document.body.style.background=bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```